# Putting a Ruler on the Side

Tags: graphics

I am writing a calculus exam, and have a problem that goes like this:  If you fold the bottom right hand corner of a piece of paper over so that it touches the left edge of the paper, what is the minimum size of the crease that you make?

As a final touch, I am going to have them fold the last page of the exam accordingly.  I would like to have a ruler on the side to help them out.  How would I do that?

Comment: Use the `textpos` or `eso-pic` package.

Comment: You could use the `tikz` package with (current page) node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with the `eso-pic` package. Naturally I have chosen a metric ruler, but you get get any other one by changing some constants. I also have made it a bit wider as usually the margins are not completely printed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{cnt}
\setcounter{cnt}{0}
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}%
    \begin{picture}(1,29)(-0,0)
      \multiput(0,0)(0,1){28}{\line(1,0){0.9}}
      \multiput(1,-0.1)(0,1){28}{\thecnt\stepcounter{cnt}}
      \multiput(0,0.5)(0,1){28}{\line(1,0){0.7}}
      \multiput(0,0)(0,0.1){280}{\line(1,0){0.5}}
    \end{picture}
      }

Some text of the document.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any way to start the text at the top, with the usual margins?

Comment: Yes, wrap the picture in `\AtTextUpperLeft{\begin{picture}...\end{picture}}` and make every 4th number of `\multiput` negative.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new package for this aim, namely `fgruler`:

http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fgruler